# Simplify "git add" After "git diff"

Tags: git

Before adding any file to git, I always call `git diff <filename>` often with additional options (e.g., "`-w`", "`--word-diff`", etc.).

Once the `diff` looks good, I stage the file for the commit via "`git add <filename>`".  The way I currently do this is by modifying the previous command line `git diff` bash call which entails deleting both the `diff` and any options which feels inefficient and a redundant approach.

How can I perform the `diff` and optionally the `add` together via the command line?

Comment: I think you're looking for the interactive mode, which you can enter via `git add -i` (or `-p`)

Comment: There's any number of IDEs and git tools which will do workflows like this. But `git add -p` might do what you want: look through the diff while adding and rejecting hunks. Otherwise you'd probably write a custom executable to do exactly what you want. Any executable named `git-foo` in your `PATH` will be available as `git foo`; just some syntax sugar.

Comment: Above suggestions are both good, but one useful tip assuming zsh or bash (and maybe other Unix shells) is that escape followed by a "." inserts the last argument of the last command. So you could set up alias `gd` for `git diff` and `ga` for `git add` and then it would be `gd <filename>` followed by `ga <esc> .`

Comment: @mikej Instead of ESC you can also hold Alt.  Same for most other ESC/Alt commands; ESC is a just compatibility option for keyboards that do not support Alt.

Comment: @0x5453 do you know if the alt versions can be used on a Mac? I had a go  but alt+. just gives `≥`

Comment: Also `$_` expands to the previous command's last argument in I think all shells, and there's history expansion options galore in most of them, `!$` for the last word on the previous command line, !#$ for the word you just typed (to e.g. repeat a long pathname), ...

Comment: @jthill: csh and derivatives (tcsh) are the exception to the "all shells" rule, but `!$` does work the same in csh/tcsh as in bash.

Comment: @mikej This may be what you want: https://superuser.com/a/85010/401176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To selectively apply diff hunks, use the `-p` aka `--patch` option.   `git add -p` applies from worktree to index, `git checkout -p` applies from index or a named commit to index and worktree, `git reset -p` applies from a commit to the index.

Your options for each hunk are

> ```
> Apply this hunk to index [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? 
> y - apply this hunk to index
> n - do not apply this hunk to index
> q - quit; do not apply this hunk or any of the remaining ones
> a - apply this hunk and all later hunks in the file
> d - do not apply this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
> g - select a hunk to go to
> / - search for a hunk matching the given regex
> j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
> J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
> k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
> K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
> s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
> e - manually edit the current hunk
> ? - print help
> ```

which you get with ? or just hitting enter.

For just generally not repeating yourself at the command line, `$_` expands to the previous command's last argument, so e.g. `git diff --word-diff @ path/to/file` and then just `git add $_`.  There's also history expansion which pulls words from history lines not commands and varies slightly by shell, `!$` is "the last word on the previous line", `!#$` is "the last word on the line I'm typing now" so in-place sort is e.g. `sort -nrk2,2 -o mylist !#$`.