# Git add after previous diff

Tags: git

In my normal git workflow I perform a `git diff filename`, control the diff then `git add filename`.

Is there any way to do this without specifying the same filename?
Looking for something like `git add -f` where `f` is some flag.

Is the best way just to write an alias for this that checks the bash history or does it exist some git functionality for this?

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48694340/simplify-git-add-after-git-diff) question with no satisfying answer.

Thanks!

Comment: the answer on that related question is exactly what you need. `git add -p` is the best thing you'll ever learn; I use it all the time.

Comment: The duplicate was the one I was linking. Not really what I asked for. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash with history expansion:

```
git diff file
git add !$
```

Or:

```
git diff file
^diff^add
```

(There are lots of clever expansions, but I use this one so often I don’t have to refer to the [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html#history%20expansion). The others sometimes trip me up, but they are good to know.)

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html#history%20expansion

Comment: @phd did you want me to include the link or?

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Up to you. I think the comment is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe not what you want, but there is the option of a process shift.

Personally, for most of the repos to which I contribute, I never put files in the directory structure that are not intended to commit and push, and I always access all files by relative path from the root dir of the clone. That way I can use a simple function for practically all my changes -

```
qp() {
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "Please enter a commit message:";
    local msg="$( [[ -n "$1" ]] && echo "$*" || echo $(head -1) )";
    date;
    git pull;
    git add .;
    git commit -m "$msg";
    git push;
    date
}
```

This lets me put the commit message on the command line (without quotes for simple ones) or leave it blank and be prompted, then it walks through a pull, add of the directory, commit, and push with just

```
qp some comment here
```

That's anonymous enough that I use the same function across repos, but it does put the onus on me to maintain process discipline.

You could probably apply a similar logic for the `diff` sequence, though.

Comment: I’d really advocate against a convenience method that encourages short (one-line) commit messages. Commits are an invaluable tool for understanding the context, they why, etc. Throwing out that information is actively harmful. Opening a real editor encourages, well, editing a good message.

Comment: You would also still regular git add when you want more granular control